# Creating Core Data predicate to get data within one-to-many relationship

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, one-to-many

I have a `Loans` entity with a `returnedDate` attribute that can contain a date or be NIL.  There is a to-many relationship with another entity, `Items` such that items can be related to many `Loans`.  I would like to create a predicate where I can find all items that do not currently have a `loans.returnedDate==NIL`.

Assume I currently have the following:

```
Loan1-item1,returnedDate=NIL
Loan2-item1,returnedDate=5/4/2012
Loan3-item2,returnedDate=NIL.
```

I would like a predicate that returns no items.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(ANY loaned.returnDate==nil)"];
```

Returns item1.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(NONE loaned.returnDate==nil)"];
```

Returns item1.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY loaned.returnDate!=nil)"];
```

Returns item1.

Can someone tell me what logic would return the appropriate results?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your goal? If you query for objects which don't have a `returnDate` nil, with that test case, you'll obtain always an element. Why do you need to return 0 elements? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated my goal to make this clear - I want to find a list of items not currently out on loan !(returnDate==nil).  I think the problem is if an item has been returned in the past, as is the case with item1 in the above example, that gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

So I used the following predicate:

```
(SUBQUERY(loaned, $sub, $sub.returnDate==nil).@count == 0)
```

and it is returning the desired results.  If you can convince me not to use SUBQUERY, please tell me how.